# Showing Blank Chart then Updating It Using Button (Google Charts)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create a scatter plot visualisation of some data using google charts. Initially, I would like the chart to be rendered but empty until such time as the user clicks a button. The reason I would like it to be drawn empty is so that the chart occupies the correct area on the page, even if no data has been loaded.

Pressing the html button will send a request to a remote server, get some data, then refresh the display after the data has loaded to show the lovely updated graph.

The problem is, even after adding the data to the TableData variable and requesting dashboard.draw(), the graph display is not updating. I feel that I must be missing something obvious here, as all the advice on stack overflow indicates that simply adding data to the DataTable and calling draw() should update the table. The controller for the table DOES seem to update to reflect the new data, but the chart itself does not.

If I have the data load instantly upon calling the drawChart() function then the graph displays perfectly. Similarly, if I don't display an empty chart, but only call draw() once the data has loaded in the data loading callback function, then the chart displays properly. This, however, doesn't look good as a chart suddenly pops onto the page.

The HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>A nice chart showing user data.</h1>
<p>Simply insert a username into the text box and click get user data.</p>
<div class="usernameInputDiv">
    <form id="usernameForm1">
        Username: <input id="usernameTextBox" type="text" name="username">
    </form>
    <div class="button">
        <button class="btn">Get User Data</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="dashboard_div" style="width: 600px; height: 350px;">
    <div id="dashboardChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    </div>

    <div id="rangeSlider_div" style="width: 600px; height: 50px;">
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

and the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart", "controls"], "callback" : drawChart});
});


//Draws a scatter chart
function drawChart() {
    //Column names for adding data
    var columnNames = ["time","bytesInAvg","bytesOutAvg","bytesInMax","bytesOutMax"];

    //initialise a data structure to store the data
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'bytesInAvg');
    data.addColumn('number', 'bytesOutAvg');
    data.addColumn('number', 'bytesInMax');
    data.addColumn('number', 'bytesOutMax');

    //Create a dashboard
    //Dashboards are used to group one (or more) graphs along with the controls for that graph
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    var options = {
        title: 'Data Sent/Received Per Minute (bytes)',
        hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
        vAxis: {title: 'Data Sent/Received (bytes)'},
        legend: '' //sets the legend to be displayed, use None for no legend
    };

    //Create chart for dashboard
    var dashboardChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
        'containerId': 'dashboardChart_div',
        'options': options
    });

    //Create controller for chart
    var dateRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'rangeSlider_div',
        'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': 'Date'
        }
    });

    //bind the chart and controller together in the dashboard
    dashboard.bind(dateRangeSlider, dashboardChart);

    //No data is loaded, so just show a blank chart for now so that it occupies the space
    //and is obvious to the user.
    updateDisplay(data,dashboard);

    //This is used to get and load data from a remote service
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        console.log("Received button press event");
        getTestData(data, dashboard, columnNames);
    });

    function updateDisplay(data, dashboard){
        //get the range of the data (just use col 1 for now)
        var yRange = data.getColumnRange(1);
        var xRange = data.getColumnRange(0);

        //Update chart axes. I would like this to be done automatically,
        //but it isn't, so for now I do it by hand.
        dashboardChart.setOption('vAxis.maxValue', yRange.max);
        dashboardChart.setOption('vAxis.minValue', yRange.min);

        dashboardChart.setOption('hAxis.maxValue', xRange.max);
        dashboardChart.setOption('hAxis.minValue', xRange.min);

        //update the display
        dashboard.draw(data);
    }

    //Test function simulating querying a server (using setTimeout to simulate delay)
    //and loading the data into a DataTable
    function getTestData(data, dashboard, columnNames){
        setTimeout(function() {
            var jsonObject = [
            {time:"2014-09-25T01:17:00.000Z", "bytesInAvg":713, "bytesOutAvg":1751, "bytesInMax":6916, "bytesOutMax":18947},
            {time:"2014-09-25T01:18:00.000Z", "bytesInAvg":146, "bytesOutAvg":328, "bytesInMax":810, "bytesOutMax":2877},
            {time:"2014-09-25T01:19:00.000Z", "bytesInAvg":44, "bytesOutAvg":73, "bytesInMax":122, "bytesOutMax":196},
            {"time":"2014-09-25T01:20:00.000Z", "bytesInAvg":41, "bytesOutAvg":69, "bytesInMax":122, "bytesOutMax":196},
        ];

        addResultToDataTable(data,jsonObject,columnNames);
        updateDisplay(data, dashboard);
        }, 2000);

    }//getTestData

    function addResultToDataTable(data, result, columnNames)
    {
      for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
      {
          data.addRow([ new Date(result[i]['time']), result[i][columnNames[1]], result[i][columnNames[2]], result[i][columnNames[3]], result[i][columnNames[4]] ]);
      }
    }//addResultsToDataTable

}//drawChart()
```

I've included a minimum working example [at jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uf5wocx9/15/). Can anyone figure out why the chart does not update correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but something wrong is happening with your dateRangeControl, so even though the data is there, it is filtered by range and not shown. You can check that using:

```
dashboard.draw(data);

console.log(dateRangeSlider.getState()) // after update, shows same date for start and end(year 1969)
```

So a quick fix would be to set a valid range for your data:

```
dashboard.draw(data);

dateRangeSlider.setState({end:new Date(), start:new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()-1))})
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uf5wocx9/17/

Comment: This does appear the fix the problem, thanks! I have subsequently found an alternative solution (see my other answer).

Comment: @FlamingBee that is indeed not obvious in the documentation, but glad you worked it out. Good luck with proyect

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, once the empty graph has been drawn initially using dashboard.draw(data), one should subsequently perform updates on the graph (ChartWrapper) itself. So instead of calling dashboard.draw(data), one should call dashboardChart.draw() directly. Doing so removes the need to alter the date range slider manually. This behaviour is slightly odd and is not obvious in the documentation.

From section 8 of the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls):

> 8. Programmatic Changes After Draw
>
> If you need to programmatically alter the dashboard state, you can do
>   so by operating directly on the ControlWrapper and ChartWrapper
>   instances that are part of it. The rule of thumb is to perform any
>   change you need directly on the specific ControlWrapper (or
>   ChartWrapper) instance: for example, change a control options or state
>   via setOption() and setState() respectively, and call its draw()
>   method afterward. The dashboard will then update to match the
>   requested changes.